# Getting error while installing phone gap in MAC osx?

Tags: ios, macos, cordova, phonegap-plugins, command-line-interface

I'm trying on install `Phonegap` in my MAC os(10.10), i have `xcode 6.1.1` installed in my system.
I'm following [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html) and [this link](http://tylermauthe.com/2013/11/09/phonegap-ios-osx-mavericks.html) to install `phonegap` and installed `Node.js` and `Command-Line Interface (CLI)`, but when i try to run this command `npm install -g phonegap`, i got error like shown in screen shot- [image]
Please suggest me what i'm missing.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `sudo`

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
```